# Substitute for using the same name on the right side

Tags: python

Sometimes, I write code like this,

```
attribute_0 = attribute_0.upper()
attribute_1 = list(map(lambda x: x.upper(), attribute_1))
```

notice the use of `attribute_i` on the right side also, this is solved if I want to do like an increment, so I could use,

```
attribute_2 += 1
```

without having to specify `attribute_2` again.
but is there an alternative for the other cases, apart from the increment/decrement/multiply/divide to avoid using the same name on the right side.

something like,

```
attribute_3 = _.upper()
```

Comment: No, those (e.g. `+=`) are predefined [in-place operators](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#in-place-operators) with corresponding magic methods (e.g. `__iadd__` for `+=`). There is no general method of making your own.

Answer (score 0):

one way to do this is to implement custom in-place methods.

```
class A(str):
  def upper(self, in_place=False):
    if in_place==True:
      A.__repr__ = lambda x: x.upper(in_place=True)
    return super().upper()
```

```
a = A('abc')
a.upper(in_place=True)
```

gives,

```
'ABC'
```

and

```
a
```

gives,

```
ABC
```

but this implementation has issues, as,

```
b = B('aaa')
b
```

would give,

```
AAA
```